# Ruby/Rails Iterating Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a table that is getting populated from an Array of Hashes. The data looks like this:

```
[
  {'key' => 'some key', 'value' => 'some value'}, 
  {'key' => 'some key2', 'value' => 'some value2'},
  {'key' => 'some key3', 'value' => 'some value3'},
  {'key' => 'some key4', 'value' => ''},
  {'key' => 'some key5', 'value' => ''}
]
```

But it can also look like this:

```
[
  {'key' => 'some key', 'value' => ''}, 
  {'key' => 'some key2', 'value' => ''},
  {'key' => 'some key3', 'value' => ''}
]
```

What's happening now is that the data where the values are all empty strings is rendering rows on my view. I don't want to render a row if ALL the values are empty strings. If the values have at least one non-empty string, I do want to render that row.

How can I stop the rendering of a row if ALL the values are empty strings? I've tried iterating through the data, which sort of works. This code:

```
<% @data.each do |r| %>
  <tr>
    <% r.each do |h| %>
      <% unless h['value'].empty? %>
        <td><%= h['value'] %></td>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

stops rendering the rows where all values are empty, but it also doesn't render the `<td>` where the row has some values that are empty because it's not rendering those `<td>`.

Comment: Why would you want to not render it? Your table is not going to line up properly unless you also vary the rendering of the table headers. This really smells like something that should be handled by passing your view better data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just skip a few `<td>` when generating a `<tr>` because it'll most probably break the rendering of the `<table>`.  ​

So, before starting to generate a « row » you'll have to make sure  that you want to display it.

```rb
<% @data.each do |r| %>
 ​<% unless r.all? { |h| h["value"].empty? } %>
   ​<tr>
     ​<% r.each do |h| %>
       ​<td><%= h['value'] %></td>
     ​<% end %>
   ​</tr>
 ​<% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: maybe add a line or two about what the mistake was and how this solves it.